# Android and respondsToSelector:

Tags: android, ios, selector

Is there an Android analogue of the `respondsToSelector:` method from Objective C?

Answer (score 3):

In Java you usually expect some interface where the method is defined. So you have the guarantee, that the object passed implements the method.

If you absolutely need the dynamic nature, use Java's reflection.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are newbiez and coming from iOS like me, I reproduce here the example found in the link provide by @afairplayer :

```
public boolean respondsToSelector(String methodName) {
    boolean result = false;
    Method method = null;
    Class objectClass = this.getClass();
    Class[] paramTypes = {};
    try {
        method = objectClass.getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (method != null)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that this may help you
http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=2fQBGOU4UfQC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=java+respondstoselector&source=bl&ots=y6ukYvNOJo&sig=maz-hWC4eE9J4HKk-pW5HBJiXLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SMtMT8HjA4ak4gSNy82FAw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=java%20respondstoselector&f=false

it's Java reflection I guess

Comment: Because external links may become broken in the future, please include details *in* your answer, citing the original link only as a source for further information.